# How to build a query that would add an extra nested level in the recordset

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

The goal is to obtain the following output:

```
SeasonA
    Leagues
        - LeagueA
        - LeagueB
        ...
    Tournaments
        - TournamentA
        - TournamentB
        ...
SeasonB
    ...
```

So far, I get this output:

```
SeasonA
        - LeagueA
        - LeagueB
        ...
        - TournamentA
        - TournamentB
        ...
SeasonB
    ...
```

The resultset returned seems to be missing a nesting level and would force me to add logic to detect/maintain the "Leagues" or "Tournaments" parent list items. Ideally, I would simply like to add an extra nested foreach in the mix.

Database structure

```
games
-----
id
season_id
league_id

leagues
-------
id
league_tournament_type_id
name
user_id

seasons
-------
id
name
user_id

league_tournament_types
-----------------------
id
name
```

Current controller query in Stats/index:

```
$this->loadModel("Seasons");

$seasons = $this->Seasons->find()
->contain([
        'Games' => function($q){
            return $q->autoFields(false);
            //->select(['season_id','league_id'])
            //->group(['Games.season_id','Games.league_id']);
        }, 
        'Games.Leagues' => function ($q){
            return $q->autoFields(false)
            ->select(['id','name'])
            ->group('Leagues.id');
        },
        'Games.Leagues.LeagueTournamentTypes' => function ($q){
        return $q->autoFields(false)
        ->select(['id','name'])
        ->group('LeagueTournamentTypes.id');
        }
    ])
->select(['id','name'])
->where(['Seasons.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
->group('Seasons.id');

$this->set(compact('seasons'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['seasons']);
```

Current loop in view:

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($seasons as $season):
?>
    <li>
    <?= $season->name?>
    <?= $this->Html->link(__('Summary'), ['action'=>'summary',$season->id])?>
    <?= $this->Html->link(__('Detailed'), ['action'=>'detailed',$season->id])?>

    <?php 
    if(count($season->games)):
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($season->games as $g):?>
            <li><?= $g->league->name?>
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('Summary'), ['action'=>'summary',$season->id,$g->league->id])?>
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('Detailed'), ['action'=>'detailed',$season->id,$g->league->id])?>
            </li>
        <?php 
        endforeach;
        echo "</ul>";
    endif;
    ?>
    </li>
<?php 
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

I'm coming from a Coldfusion background and this was trivial to do using nested CFOUTPUT with a group attribute, and a basic query with inner join:

```
<cfoutput group="season_id">
    #season_name#
    <cfoutput group="league_tournament_id">
        #league_tournament_type_name#
        <cfoutput group="league_id">
            #league_name#
        </cfoutput>
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

In Grails, I was able to rewrite a recordset into something that could easily be looped. Could this be a solution for CakePHP 3.0 too? If so, any libraries dedicated to this?

**Edit #1**

I suspect I may have to work with Collections (and use map or append)?